# How can I give discount on shipping costs?

Tags: shipping

I can't find the option to give 50% off shipping costs in Magento.

How do I create a coupon code that gives a discount on shipping?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this is going to be a bit roundabout, but should work.

Navigate to **Admin -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rule**, from there fill in the fields as needed. When you get to the "Action" tab:

- Apply: Percent of Product Price Discount
- Discount Amount: The % off you want (just the number), e.g. 50
- Apply to Shipping Amount: Yes (this targets the shipping)

Now you want to make sure you don't target any products with the discount, so continue on the "Action" tab in the "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions" section, create a rule that applies to none of your products (e.g. SKU is {some SKU that doesn't exist}).

Example:
[image: Example Promo Config]

Result:
[image: Result of example promo]

Comment: Tnx For the answer , I did exactly as you showed but still getting the message " Coupon code is not valid". should I put something special under conditions?

Comment: So this is not the best user experience, but I just rechecked my solution and it works for me if and only if a shipping method is selected before the coupon is applied (from cart estimate your shipping and taxes works). Otherwise, I get "Coupon code is not valid" as well.

You'll likely want some custom code, or at least some instructions for your customers before you try this live.

Comment: Okay, so I +1 too soon. This does not work when placing an order from the admin. 'Coupon code is not valid'. It has something to do with the sku filter.

Comment: This is not applying discount from Shipping prices, It's applying to Grand total. Any other solution for this?

Comment: its not working in magento 2

Answer (score -3):

Go to Admin -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rule

Here you are able to manage.

Thanks